# How to cake bake in Linux environment - Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

How to cake bake in Linux environment - Cakephp?
I download the latest version from cakephp website. created some tables and trying to bake process but its not working. I try to run cake bake inside cake/console but nothing happens

but in windows we need to set the environment variables like that any settings need for LINUX..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Absolutely impossible to even begin to answer without some details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, make sure the script is executable:

```
cd cake/console
chmod +x cake
```

Second, make sure that you have the php5-cli installed.  The process for this varies by system.  Googling "php5-cli" + your distribution name should get you the information.

Third, you don't need to add cake to your path as long as you don't mind navigating to the folder or typing in the full path.

```
cd cake/console/
./cake bake
```

Answer (score 4):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/cakeSiteDir/lib/Cake/Console
cd /path/to/your/cakeSiteDir
cake bake
```

Worked finally for me and did not close my console with cakephp 2.x